# Privilege Notifications

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, privileges

I'm new to Stack Overflow and just received new privileges this morning.

Now I received three new notifications about additional privileges that I received, even though I don't think I've reached the reputation points level for them. At the moment I have 13 reputation points, and I recieved notifications for the following privileges:

- Vote up
- Flag Posts
- Talk in chat

I tried voting up and it doesn't work (since I don't have the reputation points for it). What's going on?

Comment: If you have the privilege,then you should be able to do it. You must have got this privilege after gaining 15 rep. But you might have lost 2 reputation for a downvote

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: You loose privileges when your reputation points drop below the required level.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ya.. I forgot to edit my first line

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: Also, there is no evidence on the OPs [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1709629/gidil?tab=reputation) anything was downvoted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't see it. I thought that would be the only case,because i don't think new users can edit posts and gain 2 rep from it.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: He lost at least 7 points (*Talk in chat* requires 20 reputation points). As for suggesting edits, even anonymous visitors can suggest edits, there is no minimum rep for that functionality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your answer makes sense.. I didn't think that way:) . There is a chance of someone upvoting his post and again reversing it

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay TFYI :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You most likely received some points that were retracted again. You briefly did receive the required reputation points, then lost them again. This can happen when someone upvotes one of your posts, then retracts that vote within the grace period. The 10 points for an answer vote would have been sufficient to see the behaviour you described.

Another possibility is that another post of yours was deleted after you received enough points to cross the 20 point line (the *talk in chat* permission), and you dropped back down to 13 points. You can see if any posts were deleted by checking the **show removed posts** checkbox on your reputation tab.

Either way, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); privileges are tied tightly to your reputation points. If you drop below the required level, you lose them again.

Comment: That makes sense.
Thanks!