# Voting down privilege gained notification with 120 reputation - voting down not permitted though

Tags: support, bug, reputation, down-votes, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Privilege Notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149952/privilege-notifications)

I just noticed an interesting thing. I have 120 reputation on StackOverflow, and I got a notification that I'm allowed to vote down.

- I thought this is only possible with reputation > 125
- I tried (had an appropriate candidate for voting down), but the system won't let me

I might be wrong, and just guessing, but I could suspect that for example someone voted up something I wrote, but then revoked it. In that case, there should be a notification regarding this situation.

(Sorry, I can't yet post the screenshot for this, I don't have the reputation on meta to do so...)

Comment: You might see something in your [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1667004/ppeterka?tab=reputation&sort=post) if you check the "show deleted posts" checkbox.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I double checked it - I can't see any revokes. Just + points. Same results with checkbox checked and unchecked... (Or maybe I'm doing something wrong, as you can see, I'm still not a seasoned veteran in the StackExchange universe)

Comment: So it likely means someone upvoted then quickly unupvoted - this won't appear in the reputation tab.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I find this counter intuitive. Strictly as a user, I'd expect a happens-before relationship between registering reputation changes and sending notifications. Also, I'd also expect notifications about losing privileges too, no matter how quickly this happens after gaining it (or no notification at all). To eliminate chatter and unwanted garbage in the database caused by fluctuating reputation, a delay should be used for granting privileges, and sending notifications. I'm fully aware that this is a lot easier to request than to realize, and not something to be done soon.

Comment: I'm against a message for losing privileges, but as for the delay it might be a good idea, feel free to start new question tagged as [meta-tag:feature-request] giving full details of what you suggest.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thank you for your support! I'll see first if someone already suggested that.