# Did not get notification about new privilege

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, privileges

Today, I crossed 5000 reputation on Stack Overflow. So probably I expected to get a notification about privilege of `Approve or reject tag wiki edits`. But I did not get any notification. Is this because I already visited that privilege page before I reached 5000 reputation? Or is this a bug?

P.S. Today, I also crossed 2000 reputation on Meta Stack Overflow. Where I got a notification about privilege of `Edit questions and answers`. So I think this is an issue of Stack Overflow only.

My notification box: (You can see there is no notification about `Approve or reject tag wiki edits` privilege.)

[image]

Comment: Give it some time.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe As I guess: We get a notification about privilege immoderately. Because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149952/187824) [issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73673/187824)

Comment: "Today I crossed 2000 reputation on Meta..." Wow, well then.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You won't get notification because you are considered a "Veteran user", such users get fewer notifications.

There is a table originally posted [here (visible to users with 10k+ rep only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84225/orange-bar-not-appearing-when-a-new-privilege-is-earned/84317#84317) by Sam and now deleted, but probably still relevant so will repost here:

[image]

As you can see, the privilege "Approve or reject tag wiki edits" does not give notification for veteran users, while the privilege "Edit question and answers" gives notification even for veterans.

Also taken from that post:

> A veteran is a user with an associated account (on the site that was associated). If you click associate account on meta and its associated to SO, your meta account is veteran.

Comment: Okay got it. Didn't know it.

Comment: Cheers @hims, actually I was kind of expecting that with the [new notifications tab](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) in the global inbox all privileges will appear there (as the original reason to reduce their amount was the big ugly orange bar) however looks like this wasn't changed.

Comment: I pointed out several issues by now, so hopefully this is the last one: "while the privilege "Edit question and answers" give notification even for veterans." -> incorrect English, the verb should be "gives" since it is singular.

Comment: @LaszloPapp correct, now this is an actual typo.

Comment: So was the "side", or similarly how confused the "10k+" was on its own. Do not really know what you mean by "now this is an actual typo".

Comment: The "side" instead of "site" was typo in the original post. As for 10K+ it's not a typo, it's different opinions we hold and looks like Bart found a way to make it more clear.