# Why didn't non-veteran users get notified about a new privilege?

Tags: support, reputation, notifications, privileges

Just received a report from two users who crossed 15000 rep but didn't get a notification in more than two days.

- Both have accounts on other sites of the network
- Both crossed 15k with their highest-reputation account. Looks like they're not classified as [veteran users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151677/296059) on those accounts.
- Both had already crossed 3500 rep and received the same privilege in Beta.

Looks like the reason is that they already got notifications in Beta. But as requirements differ drastically, it sounds reasonable to notify them again. So I'd like to have some explanation from a SO employee.

Links to user accounts: [one](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), [two](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Both had already crossed 3500 rep and received the same privilege in Beta.

That is very well the reason. We only give you a privilege notification once per site, since there are multiple ways you could drop below the threshold again and lose the privilege, and we don't want to keep notifying users every time they end up crossing the threshold to earn a privilege again. Attempting to clear the notifications already sent out when a beta site becomes a graduated site on a per-user basis would be a lot of work for very little gain.