# Ability to suppress "participation medal" hat notifications - feature request

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I understand the obvious point of having "participation medal" type rewards, including hats (e.g. "logged into the site on specific date") in the larger design of the system.

I'm talking about hats like "Bacon", "Dreidel", "Noel", "Epiphany" or "Just here for the hats" in 2016.

The problem is, when someone is an active Stack **Exchange** user, actively participating on multiple sites, notifications **about basic hats** end up super spammy (If a user visited 7 sites, they get ~30 notifications from basic activity).

As any spam, it's negative both in basic annoyance factor, but more importantly, in **dramatically reducing signal/noise ratio in hat notifications**.

As such, I'd like to lodge a **feature request** for next years Winter Bash:

## Please have an option to opt out of notifications for "low level of effort"/"basic" hats.

(that can either be an enumerated list defined by SE, or a formula based on how many users - by absolute #, or % - got the hat).

As per [Shadow Wizard's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288995/ability-to-suppress-participation-medal-hat-notifications-feature-request?noredirect=1#comment938112_288995) this already is a feature for [Inbox notifications about privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151677/did-not-get-notification-about-new-privilege/151679#151679).

Example of spam, also courtesy of Shadow Wizard: [image]

Comment: For those who consider the hat notification as spam, SE made a special link already: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NDFq.png. Problem solved, no need to spend time on complicated solutions.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that's for people who want to opt out of hats alltogether. Considering that the request highlights "signal/noise ratio in hat notifications", this post is obviously **not** for people who just don't want hats.

Comment: "As any spam, it's negative" - from this one can only assume you consider the notifications as spam and negative. Maybe changing the wording here might help, mentioning what I explain in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151679/152859), that veteran users get less notifications. Maybe apply same behavior, e.g. user with 10 hats will be considered "veteran" and won't get notified of trivial hats.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - edited to clarify that the spam is specifically about basic hats.

Comment: Well, I still don't think it's "spammy", but here is a screenshot with FHRC if you want you can embed it to clarify what you mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8rAh.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is already code to stop the global inbox from excitedly telling you about bronze badges once you are an established user. A similar approach might refrain from telling you about "you interacted with a site on a date" hats once you are wearing a hat. No need to hate hats to be disappointed that what you thought would be a fun discovery is just another date-based "you voted" or the like. I am active on a lot of sites and I am a little fed up of those notifications, too.

Comment: I am not fed up with one marker, but when having multiple tabs open, you get the marker on all the tabs but it does not disappear when you have clicked on it once. It would already improve if it only shows up at the site you win it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm active on a lot of sites too, but I don't find these to be spammy.  Yeah, ok, today's going to bring a lot of bacon, but so what?  If the snowflake lights up, it's a quick action to click and either see "oh yeah, that" or see something that's actually news ("hey, secret hat! whazzat?").  If the interruptions bother you, you can save them up and scan the list once per day.  If having to dig through notifications to find the "good" ones bothers you, maybe reviewing the hats you care about on the Winterbash site or in your profile would serve you better.

For an optional feature that exists for three weeks a year, I don't see the benefit of investing developer time in trying to customize the notifications -- which will just lead to "why didn't you tell me about my hat?" questions from newer users, which will lead to *more* time being spent to either tune the filters or explain what's special about *these* hats as compared to *those* ones.

Treat the hat notifications for hats you don't care about sort of like those Christmas cards that come with long reports about the lives of relatives you barely know.  Glance at them and put them aside.  They're not in the same category as those frequent, annoying mailings from that organization that just *will not* take you off its mailing list dammit.  Try to take it in stride.  Eggnog might help.